# I am trying to create a new component ("hello.cmp") but when i try to run it on the server I always get error shown in the screen shot

Tags: aura-framework

I am trying to learn Aura. I am trying to create a new component ("hello.cmp") but when I try to run it on the server I always get the error shown in the screenshot. I have checked the server is up and running.

When I use this URL "http://localhost:8080/helloWorld/helloWorld.app"
it works fine:

however when i try the same with the newly created component "hello.cmp"
its doesn't work and i get the error as:

org.auraframework.throwable.AuraUnhandledException: Unable to process your request

org.auraframework.throwable.quickfix.DefinitionNotFoundException: No COMPONENT named markup://helloWorld:hello found

```
at org.auraframework.impl.DefinitionServiceImpl.getHelper(DefinitionServiceImpl.java:1427)

at org.auraframework.impl.DefinitionServiceImpl.compileDef(DefinitionServiceImpl.java:1551)

at org.auraframework.impl.DefinitionServiceImpl.compileDE(DefinitionServiceImpl.java:976)

at org.auraframework.impl.DefinitionServiceImpl.getUid(DefinitionServiceImpl.java:718)

at org.auraframework.impl.DefinitionServiceImpl.updateLoaded(DefinitionServiceImpl.java:588)

at org.auraframework.http.AuraServlet.internalGet(AuraServlet.java:306)

at org.auraframework.http.AuraServlet.doGet(AuraServlet.java:278)

at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:735)

at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:848)

at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:684)

at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1448)

at org.auraframework.http.AuraTestFilter.innerFilter(AuraTestFilter.java:314)

at org.auraframework.http.AuraTestFilter.doFilter(AuraTestFilter.java:186)
```

I have restarted the server many times but still the problem remains the same.

PLease advice how to proceed.

Answer (score 0):

I was having a similar problem when I was trying to run the aura server locally.

I think you might have the same problem I had and that is using the correct namespace. If you created a hello component try including it in your app as `<hello:hello/>`

In Salesforce it the namespace seems to default to "c"

e.g.

```
<c:component_name> / <c:app_name>
```

Below I'll explain how I understand the namespace to work, and you should play with this to get your component working:

src

src/main

src/main/webapp

src/main/webapp/WEB-INF

src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/components

src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/helloWorld <- this is the namespace

src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/helloWorld/helloWorld <- this nested folder is the component for the "helloWorld" namespace

src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/helloWorld/helloWorld/helloWorld.app

src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/hello <- different namespace

src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/hello/hello <- don't forget this component folder for the hello namespace

src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/hello/hello/hello.cmp

**helloWorld.app**

```
<aura:application>
    hello web, from the Aura sample app helloWorld
    <hello:hello/>
</aura:application>
```

**hello.cmp**

```
<aura:component>
    Hello, HTML!
</aura:component>
```

Now if you want everything in the same name space all you need to do is make sure you have the folder structure correct:

src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/helloWorld/helloWorld/helloWorld.app

src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/helloWorld/hello/hello.cmp

Now you can use
`<helloWorld:helloWorld/>` or `<helloWorld:hello/>`

I hope that helps.